# No overload for 'pnlArr_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

Just starting out on C# and I keep getting stuck on this particular piece code (more precisely the `lblArr[i, j].Click += pnlArr_Click;` line):

```
public void CreateLabelArray(int height, int width, int nrofShips)
    {
        pnlBase.Controls.Clear();
        lblArr = new Label[height, width];
        int xpos = 0;
        int ypos = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
            int column = j + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                Coordinaat pos = new Coordinaat();
                pos.X = j;
                pos.Y = i;
                lblArr[i, j] = new Label();
                lblArr[i, j].Left = xpos;
                lblArr[i, j].Top = ypos;
                lblArr[i, j].Width = 35;
                lblArr[i, j].Height = 35;
                lblArr[i, j].Tag = pos;
                lblArr[i, j].Click += pnlArr_Click;
                lblArr[i, j].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                lblArr[i, j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

                pnlBase.Controls.Add(lblArr[i, j]);
                xpos += 0;
                ypos += lblArr[i, j].Height;

                }
            xpos += 35;
            ypos = 0;
            }
    }
```

As I am trying to find out what particular mouse button was pressed on a label in an array, I thought this method might work:

```
public int pnlArr_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

The error goes away if i change MouseEventArgs to EventArgs, but then this won't work anymore:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
```

Any ideas? all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to cast eventargs inside hanglers body

Comment: Which .Net version are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 with .NET framework 4

Comment: Yes, but if i use EventArgs, I can't base my selection on 'e.button', can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that receive a MouseEventArgs as second argument is not the Click event,
but the MouseDown. Change your code in this way (also, to better readability, rename the event handler in pnlArr_MouseDown)

```
lblArr[i, j].MouseDown += pnlArr_Click;
```

Comment: This helped in a way :) the error changed to 'Wrong Type'. What should it be?

Comment: also, when I changed MouseEventArgs to Event args, i receive the following error on the e.button, in pnl_Arr:                     'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Button' and no extension method 'Button' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you reset the pnl_Click to MouseEventArgs? As a side note, do you need elsewhere the array of labels lblArr, because in the code above is not needed at all. Just replace `lblArr[i, j] = new Label();` with `Label lbl = new Label();` and use that lbl where you use lblArr[x,y].

Comment: Yeah, i have about 10 classes, and they are needed, just didn't think the whole code would be relevant...

Comment: yes I have, but still no avail. if I change                  public int pnlArr_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)            to EventArgs  the button in "e.button" is not recognised, but if I don't change it, the wrong type is returned...

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the `Click` event on a `Label` (which is defined in `Control`) is:

```
public event EventHandler Click;
```

So it doesn't take `MouseEventArgs`, just `EventArgs`.

You should look at the `MouseDown` event.

Comment: Forgive me, as I am rather new to c#, but in my case eventhandeler should be repalced by pnlArr_Click?

Comment: Not exactly. `EventHandler` is a delegate which means it's somewhat like a pointer to another method that must, in this case, have this signature - `void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);`. It means that you can attach a method to the event as long as it matches that signature. This is why your original `MouseEventArgs` signature didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the valid pattern with `EventArgs` and make use of

[Control.MouseButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons.aspx)

or make use of `MouseDown` event.